# Laravel - Eloquent How can make this relationship HasMany -> BelongToThrough

Tags: laravel, relation

How can I come up with this kind of relationship?

```
User:
 - id
 - name
 - username

Post
 - id
 - user_id
 - comment_id

Coment
 - id
 - other_id

Other
 - id
 - name
 - descripton
```

So the relationship would be:
`User - belongsToMany -> Post - belongsTo -> Comment - belongsTo -> Other`

At this relationship the `user` have many post but the `comment_id` relation is belongs to.
I cant use hasManyThrough because the relationship is different.

Is there a way to make this work?
it should be hasMany -> BelongsToThrough

I could use hasMany then on each item will call the BelongsTo, but the relationship I had is too deep.

It needs a relationship that can use hasMany then belongsToThrough such relationship

**UPDATE**
There is a belongsToMany instead of hasMany but still not sure if I could work on this

Got an alternative solution

```php
class User {
 
    public function user_post_comments () {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function getCommentsAttribute() {
        return $this->user_post_comments->map(function ($value, $key) {
            $obj = $value->comment;
            $obj->pivot=(object) [
                // Extra variable for the nested 
            ];
            return $obj;
        });
    }
}
```

```php
class Post {
    
    public function comment () {
        return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

`$this->user->comments` will return the post comment instead of posts

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

> You can get comments from users like this

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
    * Get all of the Comments for the Post.
    */
    public function comments()
    {
     return $this->hasManyThrough(Comment::class, Post::class);
    }

    /**
    * Get all of the Post.
    */
    public function posts()
    {
     return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Get Other's comment like this

```
   class Comment extends Model
   {
      
       public function others()
       {
         return $this->belongsTo(Other::class);
       }
   }
```

and get final data like this

```
$data = User::with(['comments.others'])->get();
```

Comment: My aim to be same like the hanyThrough, which only returns the final relation, with pivot or so, this does not exists on the Laravel itself, but Im hoping I could get answers :), thanks for your response by the way (y)

Answer (score 0):

Got something that will work if to add other information in the pivot.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
class ModelPivot extends Pivot
{
    public $appends = ['extra_detail'];

    public function getExtraDetailAttribute() {
        return App\Detail::find($this->attributes['detail_id'];
    }
}
```